# Parsefloat always returns NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and always returns NaN even if it is a number. I´ve been trying to fix it but i couldn´t and and everything I read was like mine.

```
  <html>
   <head>

  </head>
  <body >
  <input id="texto" type="number">
  <button type="button" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
  <br>
  <script>  
  var result =parseFloat(document.getElementById("texto").Value); 

  function calcular() {

    document.getElementById("nota").innerHTML =result;
  }

</script>

<br>
<p id="nota">d</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Capitalization matters. When getting the value from the element use `.value` not `.Value`. Also you may be able to just use `number*1` instead of `parseFloat(number)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the `value` property with lower case letter.

```
var result = parseFloat(document.getElementById("texto").value);
//                                                       ^
```

And you need to move the assignment **into the function**, because you need the actual value, not the value at start.

```js
function calcular() {
    var result = parseFloat(document.getElementById("texto").value);
    document.getElementById("nota").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<input id="texto" type="number"> <button type="button" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
<p id="nota"></p>
```

Comment: moving the assignment into the function