# parseFloat() or Number() always return NaN when read from div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, casting

I have a jquery code in which I am reading a sub-total value from a div tag and then I want to convert it into a javascript number type. So I used the below code.

```
var cart_subtotal_str = $('.pewc-total-field').text(); // so it strips all HTML tags here
var cart_subtotal = cart_subtotal_str.replace('£', ''); // removes currency sign
var cart_subtotal_num = parseFloat(cart_subtotal); // here it returns NaN
```

The content of the div is like this

```
<span id="pewc-grand-total" class="pewc-total-field"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>‎8.40</bdi></span></span>
```

Any idea why and how do I fix this?
I found that if I manually pass some string like this, it works fine.

```
var cart_subtotal_str = '12.34';
```

I have already read this answer, this question is not relevant to that
[Parsefloat always returns NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253796/parsefloat-always-returns-nan)

Comment: Yes that is why I have the .replace() method to remove the currency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal

Comment: `var cart_subtotal = cart_subtotal_str.replace('£', '').trim()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you have a non-printable character in your HTML. Most quality IDEs will display these graphically - even the SO snippet editor does this, note the red dot before `8.40`

[image]

Remove that character and your code works fine:

```js
var cart_subtotal_str = $('.pewc-total-field').text();    
var cart_subtotal = cart_subtotal_str.replace('£', '');
var cart_subtotal_num = parseFloat(cart_subtotal);

console.log(cart_subtotal_num);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="pewc-grand-total" class="pewc-total-field">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi>
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>
      8.40
    </bdi>
  </span>
</span>
```

If, for whatever reason, you don't have access to the HTML, then you can strip any non-numerical value from the HTML before you call `parseFloat()`:

```js
var cart_subtotal_str = $('.pewc-total-field').text().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
var cart_subtotal_num = parseFloat(cart_subtotal_str);

console.log(cart_subtotal_num);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="pewc-grand-total" class="pewc-total-field">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi>
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span> 
      ‎8.40
    </bdi>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: We have to have a canonical dupetarget for "there's a non-printing character in that text." Such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal

Comment: That's interesting. Actually this html code is generated by WordPress plugin so I can not edit the HTML markups. If there is any way I can identify which character it is, I can use another .replace() to remove it.

Comment: @aslamdoctor - It's character U+200E.

Comment: @aslamdoctor Indeed there is - I updated the answer to show you how. I'd suggest finding a better Wordpress plugin if it's allowing non-printable characters to be recoreded.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Makes sense, I just need numbers and decimal character. All other should be stripped :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did search, but as with questions like this it's hard to find one as the question is always around the symptom, never the cause. I'd argue that the one you suggested is a a good reference to understand the issue, but doesn't solve it.